# Jenkins: SonarQube link missing from job page's side bar

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

In the past, I configured Sonar in Jenkins by doing "Add post-build action -> SonarQube".

Now, when I do so, I get this warning:

> It is no longer recommended to use SonarQube maven builder. It is preferable to set up SonarQube in the build environment and use a standard Jenkins maven target.

To fix this, I use this Maven plugin

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</plugin>
```

and in the Jenkins job, I execute the following goals

```
-U clean test site sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://my-sonar-server
```

Everything works flawlessly, except that the SonarQube link is missing from the side bar in the job page.

When I check the log, I see the SonarQube link:-

```
[INFO] Analysis report generated in 162ms, dir size=52 KB
[INFO] Analysis reports compressed in 47ms, zip size=27 KB
[INFO] Analysis report uploaded in 81ms
[INFO] ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://my-sonar-server/dashboard/index/org.project.test:test-webapp-war
[INFO] Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report
[INFO] More about the report processing at http://my-sonar-server/api/ce/task?id=AVJgoenzoxKSuOBz_89b
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:46 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-01-20T14:02:50-06:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 67M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It appears I can add do "Add build step -> Invoke Standalone SonarQube Analysis", which will make this SonarQube link to appear, but it requires me to specify all the analysis properties manually and I find that very tedious since the `sonar-maven-plugin` handles that seamlessly for me.

My question is, using `sonar-maven-plugin` and my given goals above, how do I force Jenkins to display the SonarQube link on the job page's side bar?

I'm using Jenkins 1.645 and SonarQube 5.3.

Comment: I don't know the solution but wondering why the link is important? Since it is a static link, can you not put in the job's description page?

Answer (score 1):

You just simply tick the Sidebar Links option on build configuration as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsmbA.jpg) and put the Sonar scan linked to your project.

Answer (score 1):

- Go to Manage Jenkins > Global Configuration
- Check "Enable injection of Sonarqube server configuration as build environment variable" inside
- Check "Prepare SonarQube Scanner environment" under Build Environment of the project configuration page

Comment: I tried this solution the icon appears but is empty and in my execution job log I have the message : "Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.5.0.1254:sonar (default-cli) on project xxx : Not authorized. Please check the properties sonar.login and sonar.password." I also try with the maven goal : "clean install sonar:sonar -Djversion=${BUILD_NUMBER} -Dsonar.login=${SONAR_AUTH_TOKEN}"  But same error. Any idea to help me ?